# Crop foreground image by OpenCV GrabCut in Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, crop

I want to separate the image foreground using OpenCV.  Here is the code I want to use:

```
file_name="foo.jpg"
path=""
img=cv2.imread(path+file_name)
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
bgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
rect = (50, 50, 450, 360)
cv2.grabCut(img, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask == 2) | (mask == 0), 0, 1).astype('uint8')
img = img * mask2[:, :, np.newaxis]
```

I know that I can crop the rectangle that contains the foreground in the image by doing:

```
img[h1:h2,w1:w2]
```

But how can I find h1, h2, h3, and h4?